# systemtap: nothing for "sudo stap -L 'process("/data1/nginx/sbin/nginx").function("*")'

Tags: nginx, lua, docker, systemtap

I had installed nginx and lua in my docker image, but I didn't install them on my physical CentOS system. I installed nginx-debuginfo on both physical CentOS system and docker image. I docker run and start nginx:

```
docker run -it -p 2000:20  9cdf8f425fd9 /bin/bash /home/startnginx.sh
```

then I run "stap -L" on my physical CentOS system to see the functions of nginx,but nothing is returned:

```
sudo stap  -L 'process("/data1/nginx/sbin/nginx").function("*")'
sudo stap -d 0.0.0.0:2000:/data1/nginx/sbin/nginx --ldd -L 'process("/data1/nginx/sbin/nginx").function("*")'
```

/data1/nginx/sbin/nginx is the path of nginx on docker image. 
I don't know how to solve the problem?

Comment: @fche, I'm sorry that I duplicate questions. I really don't know how to solve the problem. I'm just learning systemtap,docker and nginx. So I don't know how systemtap on host can probe  nginx  process function in docker container.

Comment: Run a SystemTap under `strace` and check how it searches for a debug files: `sudo strace -e open stap  -L ...`